# Where to do "huge" graph calculations - Flutter, php

Tags: php, flutter, graph, weighted-graph, tree-search

I'm planning on doing an application that create the shortest possible path to some interest points. 
Each point is an activity separated from the other by a distance (e.g. p1 --50m--> p2). *Later* there will be a wait time for each point so it'll look like p1(5) --50m--> p2(15) 
The user chooses his points and then the app create the shortest possible path to do every point the less walk to do for the user. 
To accomplish that I though using a weighted graph (maybe a search-tree or something else should be better, I'm open to suggestions). 
My question is that what's the better (faster) between doing the calculation for the path search : directly in the app (Flutter - dart) or on the server and then the app shall go get the result there ?
Thanks for your help guys :D

Comment: Somewhat depends on the processing power of the server, how many simultaneous requests there might be, likely processing power of the client, algorithm to be used, etc etc etc.

Comment: Oh well that's one most important thing I didn't think about. So yeah, if I'm expecting a lot of users, I'll better to do it on each phone.
Thanks !